# Why am I getting an NRE when every control being referenced must exist and has a Text property?

Tags: c#, linq, predicate, lambda, any

I am trying to check that all required values on a form have an entry by giving them a specific tag value:

```
//HHSConsts.cs
public static int REQUIRED_FIELD = 1;

// FrmDelivery 
public FrmDelivery(NewDelivery newDel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    . . .
    SetRequiredControls();
}

private void SetRequiredControls()
{
    // Required controls will have a Tag value of "1"
    textBoxCost.Tag = HHSConsts.REQUIRED_FIELD; 
    . . .
```

Then, when the user mashes the Save button, the sanity check is performed:

```
private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if (RequiredDataMissing())
    {
        . . .

private bool RequiredDataMissing()
{
    return this.Controls.Cast<Control>().Any(ctrl => (ctrl.Tag.Equals(HHSConsts.REQUIRED_FIELD)) && (ctrl.Text.Equals(String.Empty)));
}
```

According to my lights, this is saying, "if any control has a tag of 1 (is required) and yet is empty, return false." Instead of doing that, though (beningly returning a bool val), it crashes with an NRE. More specifically:

// From application-wide exception handler: 
System.NullReferenceException: NullReferenceException
   at HHS.FrmDelivery.b__0(Control ctrl)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at HHS.FrmDelivery.RequiredDataMissing()
   at HHS.FrmDelivery.buttonSave_Click(Object sender, EventArgs args)
    . . .

Why would this be; must I de-elegantize my fancy pants RequiredDataMissing() code to get it to work as desired?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose your form contains other controls with unset `Tag` (null), so the exception.

If so, you need to modify your linq query:

```
return this.Controls.Cast<Control>().Any(ctrl => 
    ctrl.Tag != null 
    && ctrl.Tag.Equals(HHSConsts.REQUIRED_FIELD) 
    && ctrl.Text.Equals(String.Empty));
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're not setting the `Tag` property on *every* control, you'll need to check the `Tag` for a possible `null` value too:

```
return this.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                    .Any(ctrl => (ctrl.Tag != null)
                              && (ctrl.Tag.Equals(HHSConsts.REQUIRED_FIELD))
                              && (ctrl.Text.Equals(String.Empty)));
```

Alternatively, if you're only setting the `Tag` on a single type of control, like `TextBoxes`, then limit your check to those controls only:

```
return this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                    .Any(ctrl => (ctrl.Tag.Equals(HHSConsts.REQUIRED_FIELD))
                              && (ctrl.Text.Equals(String.Empty)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `.Equals` on the tag, which could be null for any controls that are not required.

Take the following simple example:

```
object o = null;  // Tags are objects
var areEqual = o.Equals(null);  // NRE
```